# Animate back and forth rotate on logo click with react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, animation, react-navigation

I'm trying to animate a menu logo to rotate when clicked. I'm successfully getting the rotation when it rotates up, but it just goes directly to 0 on rotate down instead of going through the rotate animation.

This is my component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { TouchableOpacity, Animated } from 'react-native';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

import styles from './styles';

const TabIcon = ({
  route,
  renderIcon,
  onPress,
  focused,
  menuToggled,
  activeTintColor,
  inactiveTintColor,
}) => {
  const isMenuLogo = route.params && route.params.navigationDisabled;
  const animation = new Animated.Value(0);

  Animated.timing(animation, {
    toValue: menuToggled ? 1 : 0,
    duration: 200,
    useNativeDriver: true,
  }).start();

  const rotateInterpolate = animation.interpolate({
    inputRange: [0, 1],
    outputRange: ['0deg', '180deg'],
  });
  const animatedStyles = { transform: [{ rotate: rotateInterpolate }] };
  const logoStyles = [animatedStyles, styles.logoStyle];

  return (
    <TouchableOpacity
      style={styles.tabStyle}
      onPress={onPress}
      activeOpacity={isMenuLogo && 1}
    >
      <Animated.View style={isMenuLogo ? logoStyles : null}>
        {
          renderIcon({
            route,
            focused,
            tintColor: focused
              ? activeTintColor
              : inactiveTintColor,
          })
        }
      </Animated.View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};

TabIcon.propTypes = {
  route: PropTypes.shape({
    key: PropTypes.string,
  }).isRequired,
  renderIcon: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  onPress: PropTypes.func,
  focused: PropTypes.bool,
  menuToggled: PropTypes.bool,
  activeTintColor: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  inactiveTintColor: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
};

TabIcon.defaultProps = {
  onPress: () => {},
  focused: false,
  menuToggled: false,
};

export default TabIcon;
```

I'm checking first if it has been toggled before actually rotating it. This component is being called in another parent component displaying a custom bottom tab navigation.

Should I be doing a different animation for it when it rotates down or am I missing a configuration in my current animation?

Any help and suggestion would really be much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the issue is related to the fact that when you set the initial value of `animation` because it is always set to `0` it doesn't reflect the change when you switch the menu.

You need to change:

```
const animation = new Animated.Value(0);
```

to

```
const animation = new Animated.Value(menuToggled ? 0 : 1);
```

Though making that change will cause a different problem. Because the `menuToggled` affects the start and end positions of the animation the Icon will now rotate into the correct starting position from the end position. This is not ideal.

However we can fix that by setting a default value of null for `menuToggled`. Then wrapping the animation in an `if-statement` that only runs if the `menuToggled` is not `null`.

Here is an example based off of your initial code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, Animated, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';

const TabIcon = ({
  onPress,
  menuToggled
}) => {
  const logoStyles = [styles.logoStyle];
  if (menuToggled !== null) {
    const animation = new Animated.Value(menuToggled ? 0 : 1);

    Animated.timing(animation, {
      toValue: menuToggled ? 1 : 0,
      duration: 200,
      useNativeDriver: true
    }).start();

    const rotateInterpolate = animation.interpolate({
      inputRange: [0, 1],
      outputRange: ['0deg', '180deg']
    });
    const animatedStyles = { transform: [{ rotate: rotateInterpolate }] };
    logoStyles.push(animatedStyles);
  }

  return (
    <TouchableOpacity
      style={styles.tabStyle}
      onPress={onPress}
    >
      <Animated.View style={logoStyles}>
        <Ionicons name="md-checkmark-circle" size={32} color="green" />
      </Animated.View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};
export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    menuToggled: null
  }

  toggleMenu = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => {
      return { menuToggled: !prevState.menuToggled };
    });
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TabIcon
          onPress={this.toggleMenu}
          menuToggled={this.state.menuToggled}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

I stripped down your `TabIcon` component as there was a lot of things there that were not related to the animation. You should be easily able to incorporate what I have done into your own component. https://snack.expo.io/@andypandy/rotating-icon

Comment: Really appreciate that you took the time to answer this :) I implemented the solution and it does work, but I have discovered that turning it into a class component also does the same and so I have opted for that. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I've tried Andrew's solution above and it works, but I have opted for turning it into a class component. It works the same way. See the component below.

```
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react';
import { TouchableOpacity, Animated } from 'react-native';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

import styles from './styles';

class TabIcon extends PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      animation: new Animated.Value(0),
    };
  }

  render() {
    const { animation } = this.state;
    const {
      route,
      renderIcon,
      onPress,
      focused,
      menuToggled,
      activeTintColor,
      inactiveTintColor,
    } = this.props;
    const isMenuLogo = route.params && route.params.navigationDisabled;

    Animated.timing(animation, {
      toValue: menuToggled ? 1 : 0,
      duration: 200,
      useNativeDriver: true,
    }).start();

    const rotateInterpolate = animation.interpolate({
      inputRange: [0, 1],
      outputRange: ['0deg', '180deg'],
    });
    const animatedStyles = { transform: [{ rotate: rotateInterpolate }] };
    const logoStyles = [animatedStyles, styles.logoStyle];

    return (
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={styles.tabStyle}
        onPress={onPress}
        activeOpacity={isMenuLogo && 1}
      >
        <Animated.View style={isMenuLogo ? logoStyles : null}>
          {
            renderIcon({
              route,
              focused,
              tintColor: focused
                ? activeTintColor
                : inactiveTintColor,
            })
          }
        </Animated.View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }
}

TabIcon.propTypes = {
  route: PropTypes.shape({
    key: PropTypes.string,
  }).isRequired,
  renderIcon: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  onPress: PropTypes.func,
  focused: PropTypes.bool,
  menuToggled: PropTypes.bool,
  activeTintColor: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  inactiveTintColor: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
};

TabIcon.defaultProps = {
  onPress: () => {},
  focused: false,
  menuToggled: false,
};

export default TabIcon;
```